# If I am using my familiar's special sense to see and a creature is attacking me that I see with my familiar, would they get advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, advantage-and-disadvantage, special-senses

Similar to the following:

- [Can I act normally while seeing through my familiar's eyes, per the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69101/can-i-act-normally-while-seeing-through-my-familiars-eyes-per-the-find-familia)
- [Can a spell caster attack and/or cast spells while using a familiar's senses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-a-spell-caster-attack-and-or-cast-spells-while-using-a-familiars-senses)

[Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) has this paragraph:

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.

The Blinded condition is the following:

> - A blinded creature can't see and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

So since I am blinded in regard to my own senses would I still suffer attacks having advantage against me or since I can see the attacks coming through my familiar would they attack normally? I'd say it's the latter as there is nothing saying that you can't move while using your familiar's senses. If that were an issue I believe it would be stated in the spell description as spells do what they say they do.

Answer (score 5):

### The attacker would not get advantage

You are not blinded if you look through your familiars eyes, you are only "blind with regard to your own senses". The blinded condition states

> A blinded creature can't see

You can see, just not with your own senses. If your familiar is positioned so you can see the attacker then the attacker would not get advantage on their attacks against you, nor would your attacks against them have disadvantage.

However, if your familiar is not in a position to see you, you would suffer these effects -- even independent of the question if you are blinded or not -- because you have disasvantage to hit a creature you cannot see, and a creature that is unseen has advantage to attack its target (p. 194/195 PHB).

Note that using your familiar's senses costs your action, which may make combat difficult for you if you do so, even if you can see your opponents.